# Python: Loop Prompt Back Around

Tags: python, if-statement

A lot of the errors of this Python file have been fixed but there is one last thing it's not working. I need the else statement to loop back to ask the question again if neither Yes or No is entered. You can probably see by the code what I was going for but I'm probably not even on the right track. Can someone help me with this one last thing?

```
#These are my variables which are just strings entered by the user.
friend = raw_input("Who is your friend? ")
my_name = raw_input("Enter Your Name: ")
game_system = raw_input("What's your favorite game system? ")
game_name = raw_input("What's your favorite game for that system? ")
game_status = raw_input("Do you have the game? (Yes or No) ")
game_store = raw_input("What is your favorite game store? ")
game_price = raw_input("What's the price of the game today? Enter a whole number. ")

#This is what is printed after all the prompts. There is no condition for this print.
print "I went outside today and my friend " + friend + " was outside waiting for me. He said \"" + my_name + ", did you get the new " + game_system + " game yet? You were getting " + game_name + " today, right?\""

#If the condition on the Yes or No question is yes, then this code runs.
if game_status == "YES":
    print "\"You know I got it, man!\" I said. \"Awesome! Let's play it,\" he said. \"I heard " + game_name + " is supposed to be amazing!\" We went back inside and took turns playing until " + friend + " had to go home. Today was a fun day."

#If the condition is No, then this code runs.
elif game_status == "No":
    print "\"Well let's go get it today and we can come back here and play it!\" We went down to " + game_store + " and baught " + game_name + " for $" + str(game_price) + " and we went back to my house to take turns playing until " + friend + " went home. Today was a good day. (Now try again with the No option!)"

#If the condition meets neither Yes or No, then this code runs, sending the user back to the same question again. This repeats until a condition is met.
else:
    raw_input("That answer didn't work. Try again? Do you have the game? (Yes or No) ")
```

Comment: The colon doesn't go there.

Comment: That's really not specific. There are three colons in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
if game_status: "YES"
```

isn't how you make an `if` statement. You're treating it like the syntax is

```
if some_variable: some_value
```

and if the variable has that value, the if statement triggers. In fact, the syntax is

```
if some_expression:
```

and if the expression evaluates to something considered true, the if statement triggers. When you want the `if` statement to trigger on `game_status` equalling `"YES"`, the expression should be `game_status == "YES"`, so the `if` line should go

```
if game_status == "YES":
```

Similarly, the `elif` line should go

```
elif game_status == "NO":
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed! Thank you so much! I'm still learning and this was a big help. You got the check mark.

Answer (score 2):

I would encourage to you always break to a new line after a conditional...

```
if game_status == "YES":
    print "\"You know I got it, man!\" I said. \"Awesome! Let's play it,\" he said. \"I heard " + game_name + " is supposed to be amazing!\" We went back inside and took turns playing until " + friend + " had to go home. Today was a fun day."
```

anything that is indented after the "if game_status:" will get run. And it reads better.

*edit*:: if you use single quotes for all strings then you don't need to escape the double quotes...

```
    print '"You know I got it, man!" I said. "Awesome! Let\'s play it," he said. "I heard ' + game_name + ' is supposed to be amazing!" We went back inside and took turns playing until ' + friend + ' had to go home. Today was a fun day.'
```

it's a matter of preference...but may look less cluttered.

Comment: I had no idea. I'm still new to python so that was stumping me for the longest time. Thanks for the help there! Now I just need to get these other errors fixed.

Comment: This silences the error, but it doesn't fix it. You're just doing a different wrong thing.

Comment: @user2357112 thanks! you're totally right...made an edit fix.

Comment: Honestly I prefer the escaped quotes. It's better for me to distinguish string quotes from actual quotes. There isn't any ill effects to it, is there?